# How to download additional android SDK on eclipse adt

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, adt

When i open the eclipse(adt) sdk manager it always prompt me these errors:

> Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com

and

> Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: IO Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com

And the SDK manager doesn't loads all the packages and SDK.

Does someone had the same problem? How did you solve it?

Is there another way to download all the SDK and packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because SDK manager is not able to connect to google server. Might be your firewall is blocking it. 
Things you can try :

1)Adding `adb.exe` and `java.exe` in your firewall's trusted programs may solve the issue.

2)Go To Tools -> Options in SDK Manager. Check https to force to http and try..

3)Running SDK manager with  admin priviege